# C# Hashtable & Saving

Tags: c#, wpf

I don't want to use database for this and wondering if I can somehow store input from a form into hashtable for it to be there and each time a form is filled again it would keep previous details and create another hashtable for the new details. So the details would just be stored in the code like a variable.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just storing in memory then you just load the current values.
Better yet don't discard the values.  Save the form with value and then just show the form.  But for that just bind the form UI elements to properties rather than load from and save to a hashtable a hashtable.  Or you can have  class with all the properties and you can save prior values in a List of the class.

If you want to save across execution of the .exe then you out need to serialize the data.

Comment: can you refer me to some examples?

Comment: Examples of what?  I suggest you go to MSDN and look for tutorials on data binding and collections.